# Writing a SQL query that gets information from 3 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I cant seem to figure out how to write these 2 queries on the tables that I have created. The two queries that I am trying to write are

```
Find users that have reviewed both shops and restaurants.

Find users that reviewed businesses, but not shops or restaurants.
```

The tables that I am using are

```
 reviews;
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| business_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| user_id     | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| review_id   | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       | 
| review_date | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| star_rating | int(1)  | YES  |     | 1       |     


businesses
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| business_id  | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name         | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| city         | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| state        | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| full_address | varchar(120) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

users;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name       | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| user_since | date        | YES  |     | NULL



explain is_a_restaurant;
 +--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |   
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| business_id  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| cuisine_type | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| total_seats  | int(11)     | YES  |     | 1       |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

explain is_a_shop;
 +-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
 +-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | business_id | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
 | shop_type   | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

I honestly dont know where to even start. I know I am going to join the businesses with the business ID but I dont know how I am going to find people who reviewed both shops and restaurants. can anyone help?

EDIT: WHat I have tried

For the first query: Find users that have reviewed both shops and restaurants.

```
 SELECT b.business_id
 FROM is_a_shop b 
 JOIN reviews r
 ON r.business_id = b.business_id
 JOIN is_a_restaurant k
 ON r.business_id = k.business_id;
```

Comment: Have a go first. Your Courseware / textbook will tell you where to start.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: Im trying in my sql and I keep getting errors

Comment: I dont understand working with the additional 2 tables I guess (is_a_shop and the other one)

Comment: How are you storing reviews?

Comment: @GB I updated with what Ive tried but I dont think everything is there

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the first one should look like: you can change the select statement based on what info you want to see.

```
SELECT u.name
FROM users u
INNER JOIN reviews rev ON rev.user_id = u.user_ID

WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT *
FROM is_a_shop s
WHERE s.business_id = rev.business_id)

OR EXISTS
(SELECT *
FROM is_a_restaurant r
WHERE r.business_id = rev.business_id)
```

This basically pulls all the users who wrote reviews where the business_id is found in the is_a_shop table or is_a_restaurant. you should be able to figure out the second query easily from this.

Answer (score 0):

Like most things SQL these queries can be solved in a number of different ways. These solutions should be pretty easy to understand:

Find users that have reviewed both shops and restaurants.

```
-- solution 1 - using joins:
select u.name 
from users u
join (
    select r.user_id 
    from reviews r 
    join is_a_restaurant i on i.business_id = r.business_id 
) resturant_reviews on u.user_id = resturant_reviews.user_id
join ( 
    select r.user_id 
    from reviews r 
    join is_a_shop i on i.business_id = r.business_id 
) shop_reviews on u.user_id = shop_reviews.user_id

-- solution 2: using exists - probably faster than solution 1
select u.name 
from users u
join reviews r on u.user_id = r.user_id
where exists (
    select 1 from is_a_restaurant i 
    where i.business_id = r.business_id 
) and exists (
    select 1 from is_a_shop i 
    where i.business_id = r.business_id 
)
```

Find users that reviewed businesses, but not shops or restaurants.

```
-- solution 1: using not in - probably faster than solution 2
select u.name from users u
join reviews r on u.user_id = r.user_id
where r.business_id not in 
    (
    select business_id from is_a_restaurant
    union all 
    select business_id from is_a_shop
    )

-- solution 2: using exists
select u.name from users u
join reviews r on u.user_id = r.user_id
where not exists (
    select business_id from is_a_restaurant 
    where r.business_id = business_id
    )
and not exists (
    select business_id from is_a_shop 
    where r.business_id = business_id
    )
```